# Is there a third party tool to identify documents that are candidates for backups?

Tags: windows, file-management

I have someone that has a laptop several years old.  They want to switch to a new laptop, and have not been very good about using their user home directory.  I'm looking for some tool that will traverse their drive(s), identify all documents with various configurable extensions (with an initial recommended set) and allow moving / copying right from the interface.  Sounds like explorer, right?  But maybe something a tiny bit smarter.

Comment: 1. software recommendation questions are off-topic here.   2. If somebody replaces a computer, he needs a complete backup (maybe excluding Windows folder, and program files), and not rely on document types.

Comment: "Software" could be categorized as ANY solution that is:  1.  determined by hand or command line to work, 2.  Scripted so that it can work with one click, and then perhaps, 3. Compiled into an EXE.  Yes, "software recommendations are "off topic".  However, I personally consider ANY question here on this site to fit that definition of off topic, once you think about what software actually is. START will figuring out WHAT ANY script of compiled "software" would have to do, not WHICH PACKAGED and NAMED "software".

Answer (score 1):

You need some search utility with option for using regular expressions. Personally, I use Agent Ransack.

Then, you need to enable regular expressions:

[image]

And add one of them in search bar:

```
.*\.(docx|txt|md)$
```

This one will find any docx, txt and markdown (md) files.

[image]

Comment: What if he has also older Word documents (.doc)? What if he has also Excel files, will he loose them? And if he has received something created in OpenOffice? Or a drawing in PhotoShop? CAD? I don't think it's possible to create a comprehensive list of document extensions.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Not a big problem. If it's not very convenient to have one long regex, just create several ones - one for docs (doc, docx, txt...), one for images (jps, png...), one for executable (exe, msi). Anyway, I don't see any alternative ways here.

Comment: My issue is not the length of the regex, but how you know what type of documents are there on a computer?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Well, it's on a responsibility of user. Yes, it takes some time to recollect which file types you may need. I agree, it's not very convenient.

Comment: "Well, it's on a responsibility of user" - the question is about finding a tool, which can identify those document, not to suggest some workaround which is very difficult (impossible) to use perfectly.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Are you OK? There is no reliable tool for this kind of work. Yes, you can find some utility, which will have some checkboxes "documents" or "images". But there is no guarantee it will really match all your docs and images. "Which is very difficult (impossible)" - Lol. This task is for 15-30 minutes. And there is no need to have Ph.D for it.

Comment: @JohnC. & MateJ--The OP never said they were using this myriad of potential extensions such as Photoshop (*.ps) or CAD (*.cd). AND taking John's advice, adjusting the regular expression .doc**,  .xls**, .ppt**,...etc WILL CAPTURE old and new MS Office documents, the Ransack answer just works based on the question and all these sophisticated MateJ hypothetical pitfalls are useless when applied to an UNSOPHISTICATED task.